# ${a_n}\rightarrow L$ and {$f_n$}$\rightarrow f$ pointwise. Does it follow that $f_n(a_n)\rightarrow f(L)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose  {$a_n$}$\in [0,1]$ is a convergent sequence and ${a_n}\rightarrow L$ and suppose $f_n:[0.1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous for all $n$ and {$f_n$}$\rightarrow f$ pointwise. Does it follow that $f_n(a_n)\rightarrow f(L)$.

I was hoping that I could say $lim_{n\rightarrow} \infty f_n(a_n)=lim_{n\rightarrow} \infty f_n(L)=f(L)$ but I don't know if that is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Counter-example: Let $a_{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $a_{n}\rightarrow1$.
Let $f_{n}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}.$ Note that $f_n$ is continuous.
Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }x\in[0,1)\\
1, & \mbox{ if }x=1
\end{cases}.$Clearly $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwisely. Now $f_{n}(a_{n})=(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}\rightarrow e^{-1}\neq1=f(1)$.

Comment: Similarly, suppose, for $n\in \Bbb N,$ that  $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\not \in (1/n,3/n) $ and $f_n(2/n)=n$. For any $x$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: 1/n\leq x\leq 3/n\} $ is finite, so $f_n \to 0$  pointwise . But if $a_n=2/n$ then  $a_n\to 0$ but $f_n(a_n)=n.$